# POJO to JSON - writing to string - getting {"traversableAgain" : true, "empty" : false} with Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'm having json type in my Postgres DB and getting it as `POJO`.
Then I'm trying to write my `POJO` to `String`.
`POJO` is being populated correctly, but when Jackson writes it to `String`, I get  `{"traversableAgain" : true, "empty" : false}` for nested `JSON` whose type in `POJO` is `Object`.

My `POJO`:

```
@Data
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class MyClass {

  private String property1;
  private Double property2;
  private Boolean property3;
  private Object problematicProperty;

}
```

JSON I'm retrieving from DB:

```
{
"property1" : "randomString",
"property2" : 0.3,
"property3" : false,
"problematicProperty" :  {
                "yearFromDate": [
                    "dob",
                    "yyyyMMdd"
                ]
            }
}
```

My code:

```
MyClass myPOJO = myRepository.getOne(pojoID);
ObjectMapper obj = getObjectMapper();
obj.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
obj.enable(SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE);

String stringLayout = obj
        .writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter()
        .writeValueAsString(myPOJO);
```

When I print stringLayout, I get:

```
{
"property1" : "randomString",
"property2" : 0.3,
"property3" : false,
"problematicProperty" :  {"traversableAgain" : true, "empty" : false}
}
```

instead of

```
{
"property1" : "randomString",
"property2" : 0.3,
"property3" : false,
"problematicProperty" :  {
                "yearFromDate": [
                    "dob",
                    "yyyyMMdd"
                ]
            }
}
```

I used java.lang.Object type because problematicProperty is "dynamic", sometimes it will be nested json like above, and sometimes string e.g. like this:

```
"problematicProperty" :  "randomText"
```

When testing, if I use `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode` type instead of `Object`, string is properly being written. But I can't use `ObjectNode` with Hibernate.

Why is this happening and is there a way to configure `objectMapper` to write `java.lang.Object`(that is actually a nested `JSON`) to `String` properly?

Comment: I believe that your problem is at the deserialise phase not the serialise. In the absence of a definition of problematicProperty Jackson can’t deserialise it. If a superset class with lots of JsonIgnore can be defined then that would work. Maybe Map<String, Object> problematicProperty or Map<String, List<String>>

Comment: I can't change the type to Map because, sometime problematicProperty will be String, like this: "problematicProperty" :  "randomText"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76091597/1726546) answer and [this](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-scala/issues/94#issuecomment-934174682) link
I added

```
objectMapper.registerModule(new DefaultScalaModule());
```

And now it works fine and code looks like this:

```
MyClass myPOJO = myRepository.getOne(pojoID);
ObjectMapper obj = getObjectMapper();
objectMapper.registerModule(new DefaultScalaModule());
obj.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
obj.enable(SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE);

String stringLayout = obj
    .writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter()
    .writeValueAsString(myPOJO);
```

Comment:  who would have thought. And it works for various definitions of the content of problematicProperty? Presumably it makes JsonNodes not concrete classes. Please add some more info to your answer.

Comment: Yes, it works for various definitions of the content of problematicProperty. Not sure what's going on under the hood, I didn't get into Jackson that much. If somebody knows, that info would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

A complete example would help here. If I create a dummy example from your code - see below, then it works as expected.

The `{"traversableAgain" : true, "empty" : false}` JSON is coming from what is most likely a Scala type, probably a Scala Map. It's difficult to say how to fix it without seeing where this data is coming from. One possible solution might be to change the problematicProperty field type to a (Java) Map, and convert the Scala Map when the object is constructed.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.*;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.*;

public class JacksonTest {

    @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
    @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
    public static class MyClass {

        private String property1;
        private Double property2;
        private Boolean property3;
        private Object problematicProperty;

        public MyClass() {}

        public MyClass(String property1, Double property2, Boolean property3, Object problematicProperty) {
            this.property1 = property1;
            this.property2 = property2;
            this.property3 = property3;
            this.problematicProperty = problematicProperty;
        }

        // getters and setters
    }

    private static final String TEST_JSON = "{\n" +
            "\"property1\" : \"randomString\",\n" +
            "\"property2\" : 0.3,\n" +
            "\"property3\" : false,\n" +
            "\"problematicProperty\" :  {\n" +
            "                \"yearFromDate\": [\n" +
            "                    \"dob\",\n" +
            "                    \"yyyyMMdd\"\n" +
            "                ]\n" +
            "            }\n" +
            "}";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
        final ObjectMapper obj = new ObjectMapper();
        obj.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
        obj.enable(SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE);

        MyClass myPOJO = obj.readValue(TEST_JSON, MyClass.class);

        final String json = obj
                .writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter()
                .writeValueAsString(myPOJO);

        System.out.println(json);
    }
}
```

Comment: Data is coming from postres DB, saved there previously as JSON type by hibernate.
Not sure how and why is this Scala map, but thanks to your answer it led me to the solution I wrote below.